# Using rootscope variable inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive to show google map. I am passing lattitue and longitude value from rootscope . The map is loading first time correctly but it is not loading and showing blank map if i change the lattitue and longitude values through rootscope.It does not throw any errror too.

**My map directive**

```
<map class="card map"  ng-hide="{{$scope.hideMap=false;}}"  on-create="mapCreated(map)"></map>
```

**My directive code:**

angular.module('starter.directives', [])

```
.directive('map', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      onCreate: '&',
     
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
      function initialize() {
       
           //Need to pass value from rootscope

        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng($rootScope.prodPositions.latitude, $rootScope.prodPositions.longitude);
       
       
       
        var mapOptions = {
          center:   myLatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map($element[0], mapOptions);
  
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position:  myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Pizz Hut'
        });
        $scope.onCreate({map: map});

        // Stop the side bar from dragging when mousedown/tapdown on the map
        google.maps.event.addDomListener($element[0], 'mousedown', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        });
      }

      if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        initialize();
          console.log("test lat2"+$rootScope.prodPositions.latitude, $rootScope.prodPositions.longitude);
      } else {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
          console.log("test lat3"+$rootScope.prodPositions.latitude, $rootScope.prodPositions.longitude);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: you need to re-render the directive, or the function responsible for drawing the map, every-time your rootScope variables values change.

Comment: **Side Note:**  `ng-hide` shouldn't have interpolation in it, it should be `ng-hide="hideMap"`

Comment: @PankajParkar How to re-render the directives?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to watch for changes on the `$rootScope.prodPositions` variable, and then you need to recompile your directive.

To recompile your directive you nedd to add this inside your link function:

`$compile($element.contents())($scope);`

and add a `$compile` service as a DI.

[Angular $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: How to recompile a directive? Could you please  give me any reference?

Comment: You need to add `$compile($element.contents())($scope);` in your link function after detected changes.